# Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead - error on query

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, parse-platform

I have received a Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead occured on the following line:

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
```

I have been trying to troubleshoot since a while, but is still having difficulties.

Below is my complete code

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public interface Constants {
          String LOG = "com.dooba.beta";
        } 

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);


        return view;
    }

private void setConversationsList() {
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>(); 

    // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
    query.setLimit(1);
    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
    //query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
    //query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
    query.orderByDescending("Name");

    Log.d(Constants.LOG, "");


    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(java.util.List<ParseObject> objects,
                ParseException e) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");


    ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

     // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
     // data.
     imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_pict));
     imageView.setParseFile(image);
     imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
       @Override
       public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
         Log.i("ParseImageView",
             "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
       }
     });
    }



    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {



        public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistname, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i=0; i<userlistname.size(); i++) {
                    names.add(userlistname.get(i).get("Name").toString());








                    //       names.add(userList.get(i).getParseObject("ProfilePicture").;


                }




                usersListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistname);
                namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                        openConversation(names, i);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}




public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error finding that user",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}


}
```

Thanks in advance, and all the best.

Update
In response to Rod_Algonquin
[image]

In response to Haresh
[image]

Update 2
[image]
code

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public interface Constants {
        String LOG = "com.dooba.beta";
    }

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);


        return view;
    }

    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>();

        // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        //query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        //query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query.orderByDescending("Name");

        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "");


        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) {

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");


                ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

                // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
                // data.
                imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_pict));
                imageView.setParseFile(image);
                imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        Log.i("ParseImageView",
                                "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }});



        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {



            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistname, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<userlistname.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userlistname.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistname);
                    namesArrayAdapter =
                            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                            openConversation(names, i);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }




    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error finding that user",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Update:

[image]

Updated code 4

I am encountering 2 problems:
1) object cannot be resolved

2) 
The below error is just underline in yellow, but it does not render when the activity loads
`The method done1(List<ParseUser>, ParseException) from the type new FindCallback<ParseUser>(){} is never used locally`

update 5

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public interface Constants {
        String LOG = "com.dooba.beta";
    }

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<String> age;
    private ArrayList<String> headline;
    private ArrayList<String> activityname;

    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber(
            "Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString(
            "Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container,
                false);

        return view;
    }

    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        age = new ArrayList<String>();
        headline = new ArrayList<String>();
        activityname = new ArrayList<String>();

        alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>();

        // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query.orderByDescending("Name");

        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "");




        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users,ParseException e) {

                // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");

                ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");


                ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

                 // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
                 // data.
                 imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_pict));
                 imageView.setParseFile(image);
                 imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                     Log.i("ParseImageView",
                         "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
                   }


             });
            }
        });

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistname, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistname.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userlistname.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
                }
            });

        }
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistheadline, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistheadline.size(); i++) {
                        headline.add(userlistheadline.get(i).get("Headline")
                                .toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistheadline);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_all,
                            headline);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done2(List<ParseUser> userlistage, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistage.size(); i++) {
                        age.add(userlistage.get(i).get("Age").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistage);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            age);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done3(List<ParseUser> userlistactivity, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistactivity.size(); i++) {
                        activityname.add(userlistactivity.get(i)
                                .get("ActivityName").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistactivityname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            activityname);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error finding that user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to replace this code,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public interface Constants {
        String LOG = "com.dooba.beta";
    }

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<String> age;
    private ArrayList<String> headline;
    private ArrayList<String> activityname;

    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber(
            "Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString(
            "Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container,
                false);

        return view;
    }

    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        age = new ArrayList<String>();
        headline = new ArrayList<String>();
        activityname = new ArrayList<String>();

        alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>();

        // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query.orderByDescending("Name");

        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "");

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryo = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");

        queryo.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        queryo.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        queryo.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        queryo.setLimit(1);
        queryo.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        queryo.orderByDescending("Name");


        queryo.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {


            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> object, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");

                ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView()
                        .findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

                // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to
                // be replaced by the fetched image
                // data.
                imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.profile_pict));
                imageView.setParseFile(image);
                imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        Log.i("ParseImageView",
                                "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length
                                        + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistname, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistname.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userlistname.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            public void done1(List<ParseUser> userlistheadline, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistheadline.size(); i++) {
                        headline.add(userlistheadline.get(i).get("Headline")
                                .toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistheadline);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_all,
                            headline);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            public void done2(List<ParseUser> userlistage, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistage.size(); i++) {
                        age.add(userlistage.get(i).get("Age").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistage);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            age);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            public void done3(List<ParseUser> userlistactivity, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistactivity.size(); i++) {
                        activityname.add(userlistactivity.get(i)
                                .get("ActivityName").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistactivityname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            activityname);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error finding that user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I unfortunately encountered some minor errors and have attached a picture under the update section of my initial post.

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit. Its a major step forward in resolving the issue I had. I made a few edits, and have one typo left. I have attached a picture along with an updated code under the update section of my initial post. Thanks

Comment: can you please move your cursor to this line and let me know which error hint it showing to you ?

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. It gives me the following: The method findInBackground(FindCallback<ParseUser>) in the type ParseQuery<ParseUser> is not applicable for the arguments (new FindCallback<ParseObject>(){})

Comment: Hi, I have resolved the minor issue i had but in doing so, i encounter a minor formating issue. I have kindly attached a picture and an update code under the update 3 section of my initial post

Comment: Thanks for all your help Haresh. If I can ask you a small favor is that I encountered another 2 minor issues in my code that is similar to this question. I have updated my issues under the update code 4 of my initial post.

Comment: findInBackground() can only execute Overrides done() and it can not execute your done1,done2,done3 custom methods.

Comment: the problem when I don't rename it is that I have a duplicate method being called

Comment: your right i should have not define it. I adjusted my code and updated it under update 5 section of my initial post. It has a few formating issues. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**problem:**

`query` is actually out of scope, you put the `query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {` outside the `public void done(java.util.List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e)` thus giving you that error because the query variable is inside the `done` method.

**solution:**

Put it inside your done method of the anonymous class

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(java.util.List<ParseObject> objects,ParseException e) {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");


                ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

                // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
                // data.
                imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_pict));
                imageView.setParseFile(image);
                imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                            Log.i("ParseImageView",
                                    "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                });

                //////////PUT IT HERE///////////

                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

                    public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistname, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            for (int i=0; i<userlistname.size(); i++) {
                                names.add(userlistname.get(i).get("Name").toString());

                            }

                            usersListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistname);
                            namesArrayAdapter =
                                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                            R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                            usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                            usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error loading user list",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response and detailed explanation. I unfortunately encountered some minor errors and have attached a picture under the update section of my initial post.